# Create a matrix with specific conditions in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to know how many square binary matrices exist with the conditions that they have two ones per row and column and that in addition the elements of the main diagonal are zero. 
I want to create a program that, given the size of a matrix, calculates how many there are that meet those conditions.

This is what I've been doing for the moment, but the right calculations don't come out. In a 3x3 matrix I get 3 possibilities and there is only 1. I think the same matrix is being counted several times.
How can I do it?
Thank you

```
import numpy as np

def funcion(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n))
        while a[i].sum() != 2 or a[:, i].sum() != 2 or a[i][i] != 0:
            a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n))
        if a[i].sum() == 2 and a[:, i].sum() == 2 and a[i][i] == 0:
            total = total + 1

    print(total)
    return total
```

Comment: describe it with an example

Comment: Whyyyyy are you using random? You won't get all solutions and you will get repeated solutions! Use paper first because that's a maths (combinatorics) problem!

Answer (score 0):

Random is right out - as commented this is a mathematical problem:

```
def funcion(n):
    # every row has n - 1 slots that can be filled with 1 as one must be 0
    # (the diagonal) - we must pick exactly two slots
    slots_with_one = (n - 1) * (n - 2) // 2
    # now that we picked those in all other rows we must put a one on those
    # columns exactly - if not that column won't have two ones, so we're done
    return slots_with_one

print(funcion(3))
print(funcion(4))
print(funcion(5))
```

Comment: i see what you mean, but how would you change your code to make that every row and every column has exactly two 1?

Comment: Thank you very much, but one last question: why do you divide between 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very intuitive solution, you can even print out the matrix rows and see for yourself.
The first part of the code sets the specifications of the matrix. 
The issue here is to treat [1,1,0] or [1,1,1] as a lego block, to build the matrix. 
Then you can try all the possible combinations of this block to fill the matrix, 
leaving always the space for the 0 in the diagonal.

Within the commented lines you can verify some of the rows printings to understand what we are doing and why.
The only special case is the matrix of size 3, because is the same size of the "lego block", which means
the variable 'x' is 0 and its place is fixed because of the diagonal.
The result is the value in howMany.

```
    import itertools
    size        = 4 #square matrix (mandatory diagonal case)
    binary_data = [1,1,'x'] #'x' can be either '0' or '1'
    changePos   = (size - 1) #1 is 0 fixed

    if size > 3 :

        comb = list(itertools.permutations(binary_data,changePos))
        rowsX = [list(i) for i in comb] #convert tuple into lists
        #[[1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], [1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], ['x', 1, 1], ['x', 1, 1]]

        # for 0
        rows0  = [[0 if y == 'x' else y  for y in x] for x in rowsX]
        #[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]

        # for 1
        rows1  = [[1 if y == 'x' else y  for y in x] for x in rowsX]
        #[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

        rows = []
        # all possible combinations, without repetition
        for row0 in rows0:
            if row0 not in rows:
                rows.append(row0)
            for row1 in rows1:
                if row1 not in rows:
                    rows.append(row1)
        #[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
        # 1st row can be [0,1,1,0] or [0,1,1,1] or [0,1,0,1] or [0,0,1,1]
        # 2nd row can be [1,0,1,0], [1,0,1,1], [1,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1]]

        howMany = len(rows)**size

    elif size == 3

        howMany = 1 #only one possible matrix
        """
        0,1,1
        1,0,1
        1,1,0
        """

    else: # < 3
        print('It doesn't comply the matrix specifications' )
```